# How to recover from freeze while nothing works?

Tags: 14.04, freeze

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. Sometimes Ubuntu freezes and i can't do anything anymore. 
What can i do to recover from this situation?
In windows it was simple i just had to use task manager via `alt`+`ctrl`+`delete`.
Is there something like this in Ubuntu?
I know that there is `xkill` and System Monitor in Ubuntu but when Ubuntu freezes i can't use any of them and i can't open terminal and even though i have set a shortcut for `xkill` but still after freezing happens i can't use `xkill`. It's like after freezing nothing works.

Comment: @karel Is there a way not to reboot the system?

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Backspace keyboard combination to kill X server: 1. From terminal type: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` 2. Press Enter key 5 times to skip all keyboard related options except for the terminate X server part. 3. Select Yes at the X server screen and press Enter. Wait a bit while everything configures and close the terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd> and while holding on these two keys type <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>. for more information you can found you answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes/36717#36717).

Comment: So you mean nothing else can be done but rebooting?

Comment: R:  Switch to XLATE mode
E:  Send Terminate signal to all processes except for init
I:  Send Kill signal to all processes except for init
S:  Sync all mounted file-systems
U:  Remount file-systems as read-only
B:  Reboot